# How can I open javahelp from javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, javahelp

I have used JavaHelp with swing and I could do

```java
  try {
            URL helpURL = this.getClass().getResource("/help/help.hs");
            HelpSet helpset = new HelpSet(null, helpURL);
            HelpBroker browser = helpset.createHelpBroker();
            browser.enableHelpOnButton(MY_BUTTON, "main", helpset);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ...
        }
```

Where MY_BUTTON was a swing button, but I cannot do the same on JavaFX since JavaFX buttons are not swing/awt buttons.

How could open javahelp using JavaFX buttons?

Comment: You can embed a Swing button in a JavaFX [SwingNode](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.swing/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html).  I recommend setting the system look-and-feel, to make the Swing button look similar to the JavaFX UI.

Comment: @VGR "I recommend setting the system look-and-feel, to make the Swing button look similar to the JavaFX UI." -> is that even possible without a lot of work?  I don't know Swing very much, I just thought it might be difficult to achieve.  I guess for just a single control like a button, it might not be too hard, just not sure.

Comment: @jewelsea Should be as easy as in a regular Swing application:  `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName())`  Of course, the difficulty in mixing Swing with JavaFX is calling things in the proper threads (AWT event dispatch thread for Swing constructors and methods, JavaFX application thread for JavaFX).